# What to name a class that only provides a static property?

Tags: c#, oop

I am working on familiarizing myself with the correct names of classes based on what their usages are.  I have the following class that only offers a static property outside of itself, and am wondering if "Provider" would be fair to add to the name of the class, or if it is misleading?

This is my "MyConfigurationProvider" class:

```
public static class MyConfigurationProvider
    {
        private static Lazy<MyConfiguration> _myConfiguration;

        public static Lazy<MyConfiguration> MyConfiguration
        {
            get
            {
                return _myConfiguration??
                    (_myConfiguration= GetMyConfiguration());
            }
        }

        private static Lazy<MyConfiguration> GetMyConfiguration()
        {
            var myOptions= new ConfigurationOptions();

            return new Lazy<MyConfiguration>(() => new MyConfiguration(myOptions));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is to name it whatever makes it easiest for you to understand the intent of the class...

If you need to work with other people, then have a quick chat and see if that name makes sense to them.

In the case of the suffix `Provider`, in a .NET context that is typically used to indicate that you're following a [Provider model approach to implement functionality that's exposed via an abstract factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provider_model).

Answer (score 2):

Your MyConfigurationProvider class is implementing the Singleton pattern. You may want to call it ConfigurationSingleton.